# how we checked some checkbox in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new in angular 6.I need to mark check-box .

i have two Arrays:

```js
 this.skillArray = [
        {ID: 1, name: "الغطس"},
        {ID: 2, name: "الحريق"},
        {ID: 3, name: "المعالجة"},
        {ID: 4, name: "الميكانيكا"},
        {ID: 5, name: "السيول"},
        {ID: 6, name: "التغريز"},
        {ID: 7, name: "الكهرباء"},
        {ID: 8, name: "الاحتفالات"},
        {ID: 9, name: "المناسبات"},
        {ID: 10, name: "الصلاة"}
    ]

  var splitstr = ["9", "7"];
```

Then we want to check 9 & 7 id are checked in checkbox. I  try to solve it and then success to mark these checkbox but i also perfomed a onchenge function in checkbox to post the value. So the problem is those checkbox are checked value is not pushed to array.So how to solve it.

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div *ngFor="let data of skillsArray">
<p><input type="checkbox" [checked]="inputChecked(data.ID)" (change)="onChange(data.ID, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.name}}</p>
</div>

</form>
```

```js
inputChecked(id:any) {
    let checked = false;
    console.log(this.splitstr);
    for (let l = 0; l <this.splitstr.length; l++) {
    let temp = this.splitstr[l];
    if (temp == id) {
    checked = true;
  }
}
return checked;
}


onChange(value: any, isChecked: boolean) {
  const skillFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.VFields;
  if (isChecked) {
  skillFormArray.push(new FormControl(value));
  }
  else
  {
  let index = skillFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == value)
  skillFormArray.removeAt(index);
}

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: those check-boxes are chcked already push in skillFormArray .

Comment: @AakankshiGupta, Here no one understand Hindi, Please make your comment in English..

Answer (score 0):

you should try sth like this:

> your component code:

```
  activeEls = [];
  neededValues = [1,3];

  changeStatus(car: Cars){
    car.checked = !car.checked;
    if(car.checked){
      this.activeEls.filter(function(value, index, arr){

        return value == car.id;

      });
    }
else{
      this.activeEls.splice(this.activeEls.indexOf(car.id),1);
    }
    console.log(car.id, " status= ", car.checked);
  }

  ifOneAndThreeIsActive(){
for (let ca of this.cars){
  if(this.activeEls.includes(ca.id))
    continue;
  if(ca.checked)
    this.activeEls.push(ca.id);
}
let concur = 0;
for(let j = 0, l1 =  this.activeEls.length; j < l1; j++){
  if(this.neededValues.length <= j && !this.activeEls.includes(this.neededValues[j])){
    continue;
  }
  ++concur;
  if(concur == this.neededValues.length && this.activeEls.length === this.neededValues.length)
    console.log(this.neededValues, 'correct');
  console.log(concur);
}
console.log(this.activeEls);
```

}

> your HTML file:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let car of cars">     
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="changeStatus(car)" [checked]="car.checked">
    </li>
  </ul>
      <button class="btn btn-info" (click)="ifOneAndThreeIsActive()">Check if 1 & 3 are active</button>
```

<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="pushNum(2)">push

or if you only need this to work when only 1&3 is selected, you will need to change the numbers in my example.

does this solution suits you?

Comment: all the Arrays are dynamic.

Comment: So, you want that 1 & 3 it would be a dynamic array, isn't it? but other is okay, right?

Comment: I've changed it. review it if it's what you needed